# Opposite prefix for de-, with regard to the words despection, circumspection, and respect

Tags: prefixes

I'm looking for the proper prefix for what kind of "spectating" would make an etymologically correct connotation towards "looking up", where despection and "despising" is looking down on something.

I can edit my inquiry/body, if I'm not adhering to this forum's decorum/rules.

Comment: despection?? What is that?

Answer (score 1):

If there were such a word, it would be *conspect,* or else a new sense of *aspect.* As Lewis and Short says, Latin [*conspicio*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconspicio1) and [*aspicio*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daspicio) can mean "to look upon with admiration." Since such *-spicio* roots (and their *-spectus* participles) are the sources of the English *-spect* words, those would be the logical choices.

Of course, neither of these prefixes means "up"; *con-* is typically an intensifier, and *ad-* means "towards."

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good prefix that fits the pattern you want.

The prefix for *despise* is described in the Oxford English Dictionary, "de-, prefix," definition 1a:

> a. Down, down from, down to: as depend v.1   (dependent adj., dependence n., etc.), depone v., depose v., depress v., descend v., devour v.   (all from Latin). So of English formation, debreak v.

It's difficult to find an antonym prefix that is generative in English. For instance, looking at *descend*, the antonym in English would be *ascend*, with the Latin *ad* (abbreviated in the word) forming a prefix that could mean to/toward, at/by, on/upon/against, or (as with the Latin *ascendo*) up. ([Perseus Tufts, Lewis & Short Dictionary, ad, II.B.1.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ad&la=la#lexicon)). However, that is not generative in English, and only a few words represent that sense of *up*. *Aspicio* or *adspicio* means to look toward, not look up at, and doesn't constitute a valid opposite in the way you're looking for ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aspicio#Latin)). (In English, *aspect* is not an opposite of *despection* or *despise*.)

For the Latin roots of *despise* or *despicio*, the opposite could be *suspicio*, but it too poses problems. *Sub* means *under*, but for *suspicio,* the resulting word means something like looking *from* below, that is, looking upwards ([Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=suspicio&la=la#lexicon)):

> I. To look up or upwards, to look up at a thing.

That could be literal or metaphorical, e.g., looking up at the clouds or admiring someone else. If that were in English, that would be exactly what you wanted. However, a second meaning in Latin is more familiar to us:

> II. To look at secretly or askance; hence, by meton. (effectus pro causā), to mistrust, suspect

Indeed, the resulting English usage mainly means to mistrust someone, or to believe them responsible for something. The meaning of looking up is mostly absent from English, even though *sub/sus* is the prefix that would be used to say that in Latin.

The closest you'll get, in English, is obscure terminology. In heraldry, *suspectant* means that something is looking upwards (OED, "[suspectant, adj.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195140)"). It only holds that meaning through direct connection to Latin; anyone who doesn't know Latin will likely not know why the term doesn't mean "suspicious." Anyone who only knows a little Latin will wonder how *sub* comes to make a word mean looking up. To be colloquial, it's a hot mess.